# Office 365 REST API, Outlook Streaming Service - User Account Blacklisted?

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

We've been using Outlook's [streaming service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-streaming-rest-operations) for emails and events for about a month and a half and haven't run into any issues. However, yesterday at around 6:45 PM Pacific Time I stopped receiving notifications for the email account: `matthewbordas@outlook.com`. There were no errors transmitted back to us and the stream kept reconnecting and the subscriptions weren't expired. This problem is still persisting to this moment, yet all our other user accounts are fine. I should add that this account has been used significantly for testing and the content of the emails sent to and from it have been gibberish; could the API blacklisted have it and marked it as spam? That's the only reasonable conclusion I can come to, but there isn't any documentation on this case and I haven't received any messages from Microsoft indicating that such a restriction was placed on the account. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!